# Templates and pulling data from my own database (not wordpress one)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm pretty new to wordpress. I have read a lot about templates, template pages, etc... and I would really apreciate if someone could confirm my thoughts, ideas about how to build my Homepage with wordpress (I won't be using it for blooging, but my enterprise webpage).

The main problem is that I need to have a page, where a little list of items will be shown. After one of them is clicked another page will be shown with information about the item like a pic, short description, etc... etc... This Item information page will be using a template page where data from my own CMS database has to be inserted in the template holes.

All examples I have seen in wordpress are about pushing data in wordpress database and showing it using WP API. But, what about if I just want to use wordpress as a template system, with all its plugins, etc... and pull the data needed to be shown from another database (our CMS)?. Could anyone suggest best practices for this, or a better aproach?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

is your wordpress database in the same database as your own? 
ie: you can access the wp tables along with all your other tables? 
if so you can use the wp api, to connect,

using the normal connection methods..

if the tables are not in the same database but located under the same account on your host, you could use the same method shown in this [thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database)...

```
$mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
$rows = $mydb->get_results("select Name from my_table");
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($rows as $obj) :
   echo "<li>".$obj->Name."</li>";
endforeach;
echo "</ul>";
```

if the database is in another location, outwith the current server just change the localhost to your server ip and port to connect, ie:

```
$mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','192.168.1.1:6807');
```

good luck

Marty

Comment: So, the way this has to be done is more or less the ussual for any web, the only difference is using wordpress db class if you want?. I was thinking about defining the template in WP and using something like custom fields to tell WP what to push in each hole. Don't really know if this custom fields could be of help for this, just read about them and seemed something to take into acount. I mean, do something like "The loop" does but with my own data (The one extracted from my CMS). Sorry if the explanation is a bit cripting. It is a bit difficult to explain my objectives. Thanks.

Comment: without looking at your system, or database, would it not be more benificial to export your data from your database and incorporate it into wordpress, taken advantage of its pages and posts? and possibly using the custom fields as and when you need them? just seems a little bit of a work around jsut to use wordpress as a template system..?

Comment: Well, We have a bunch of data in our CMS. It will be a real pain to port the data to WP database and the duplicity of it will be really difficult to mantain. Perhaps use wordpress is not the best option, but I like a lot all its plugins (SEO, Breadcrumb, etc... etc...). Another option would be to start inserting new data directly into wordpress system, and port the old one, but don't know if there's any doc to inject data into its cms structure. What do you think?

Comment: if you can dump your old database to csv, and sift through that, you can easily create a new csv to import to wordpress using the likes of blogpig, but i suppose if its huge it may well take a while,